Are closing hash marks ever necessary in headers?
When posting a question, the following help is available:
Use hash marks for multiple levels of headers

# Header 1 #
## Header 2 ##
### Header 3 ###

But the closing hash marks don’t seem to be necessary.
For example,
# ABC #

and
# ABC

give the same result (as shown below):
ABC
ABC
Are closing hash marks ever necessary in headers?

According to the official help section, the closing # is entirely optional.
I played around with it a little bit and it seems like you can't trick it since it requires an actual line break at the end, e.g. # header #<br>text will not close the header.
